# Database schema for Admin, User and Subscriber Laravel

Tags: database, laravel-5.4, database-schema

I am working on a new project and I need a database schema that will work as expected from onset. I intend building a mobile app where subscribers to a particular Teacher can download the App designed for that particular Teacher they want to subscribe to their contents. There are different Users of the system which are `Administrators, Teachers and Subscribers`.

Let me start by explaining the roles:

**Admin**
The overall Administrator of the system.

**Teachers**
A teacher can post articles, videos, pictures etc

**Subscribers**
A subscriber can subscribe to contents posted by a Teacher and access only that Teacher's articles, videos, pictures etc

**What is on ground**
Laravel uses the `users` table to store users authentication information. It therefore means I will store the Admin, Teacher and Subscriber authentication in the `users` table and use `roles` to differentiate what they can do and access.

**Problem**
Problem I face now is that subscribers can download not just Apps designed for the Teacher they wish to subscribe to but any other Teacher of the system that post news, pictures etc

There is also the problem of a Subscriber who wish to download the App of another teacher and wishes to register, he can't register because they can't use the same email twice and I don't want a situation where a Subscriber will want to register and an error pops-up and inform them that the email is already in use.

**Question**
How can I design this kind of schema.

**Disclaimer**
I may not know the current terms to use for these cases, but I can learn.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to learn first database design then you could easily handle this problem. Here is one tutorial link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I_rxqSJAj6U
. You could find more tutorial on web :)

Comment: From my question, you will know that I know what database is and can design one.

Answer (score 0):

you should learn database design and schema from here 

[Laravel Database](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/database)

or learn basic from laracasts.com

for Roles Try https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust
this package is for Role System

Comment: From my question, you will know that I know what database is and can design one.

Comment: if you need role's base app so go for entrust